# How to get current color property of a widget?

Tags: flutter, animation, colors

I am trying to build a widget which has a changing colors. For example, it starts with white and animate the color slowly over time to become red. Then, I need to get its color when the user press a button. Now, I am trying to achieve this by using **AnimatedContainer**. It does the exact animation I want. However, I can't get the color property at specific time(e.g pressing a button). Is it possible to do this using standard Flutter widgets? Or, is there any Flutter package to satisfy this need?

Comment: Have you tried assigning a unique key and find.byKey() the widget to query the widget attributes? Not sure what attribute would hold current color but you could inspect the widget in the debugger to see what's available to query.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. Most properties(size, position...) can be get using this but I can not get the color.

Comment: do you want this process in the test process or in your application?

Comment: @Abbasihsn In my application

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `ColorAnimation` widget. `ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget` (`AnimatedContainer` uses this) you can animate a widget when a variable changes in your case a color. You will need to use a `ColorTween` for the transition.

With this you could create getter in the State of the animation that gives the current `Color`.

Here is an example implementation:

```
class TestColor extends ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget {
  const TestColor({
    Key? key,
    this.onTap,
    this.color,
    Curve curve = Curves.linear,
    required Duration duration,
    VoidCallback? onEnd,
  })  : super(key: key, curve: curve, duration: duration, onEnd: onEnd);

  final Color? color;
  final void Function(Color? color)? onTap;

  @override
  AnimatedWidgetBaseState<TestColor> createState() =>
      _TestColorState();
}

class _TestColorState
    extends AnimatedWidgetBaseState<TestColor> {
  ColorTween? _color;
  Color? get color => _color?.evaluate(animation);

  @override
  void forEachTween(TweenVisitor<dynamic> visitor) {
    _color = visitor(_color, widget.color,
            (dynamic value) => ColorTween(begin: value as Color))
        as ColorTween?;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Animation<double> animation = this.animation;
    final Color? color = _color?.evaluate(animation);
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => widget.onTap?.call(color),
      child: Container(
        color: color,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With this you could get the color with:

```
//The key
final GlobalKey<_TestColorState> color = GlobalKey();

//The widget
TestColor(
  key: color,
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
  color: Colors.red,
)

//How to get the current color
color.currentState?.color;
```